# Assets pipeline and vendor assets. How do you add them to be precompiled in Rails 4?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

This is incredibly frustrating.

I have added a few CSS files to my vendor assets, and I cannot seem to get them to get precompiled, or at least FOUND by my production server.

The files are found in something like this:

```
/vendor/assets/stylesheets/cssfw/style.css
/vendor/assets/stylesheets/cssfw/app.css
/vendor/assets/stylesheets/cssfw/plugins.css
/vendor/assets/stylesheets/cssfw/custom.css
```

And they're loaded like this on my application.css

```
*= require cssfw/style.css
```

And inside style.css

```
@import url(app.css);
@import url(plugins.css);
@import url(custom.css);
```

This works fine in my development environment (obviously), but all of those 4 CSS files cannot be found anywhere in the assets in production.

I'm obviously missing to include something, but what?

If I use something like this in production.rb:

```
config.assets.precompile += %w( *.css )
```

I get a barrage of errors, cause then it goes through every single stylesheet I have in the /vendor/ directory. if I try to be specific (such as specifying style.css), the same initial errors persist, and style is nowhere to be found.

How are they supposed to be included exactly? Preferably, I wouldn't want to include ALL the vendor assets files, cause there's only a handful that I'm actually using, but the folder contains around 20 or so that I haven't yet configured.

I'm using Rails 4.1.6 with Ruby 2.1.0, on Apache Phusion Passenger.

Answer (score 1):

The trick was in changing `@import` to `*= require`, cause @import isn't following the assets pipeline. I'm still unclear of why that happens, but I changed this in style.css, which after all was actually being loaded all this time.

In my application.css:

```
*= require cssfw/style # /vendor/cssfw/style.css
```

And in the first part of style.css:

```
/*
*= require cssfw/app         # /vendor/cssfw/app.css
*= require cssfw/plugins     # /vendor/cssfw/plugins.css
*= require cssfw/custom      # /vendor/cssfw/custom.css

*= require cssfw/plugins/animate         # /vendor/cssfw/plugins/animate.css
*= require cssfw/plugins/box-shadows     # /vendor/cssfw/plugins/box-shadows.css
*/
```

This would make Rails to look for them in the proper places in the vendor pipeline, although I'm being forced to practically include the entire path, minus cssfw. If I leave it out, it works fine in development, but production cannot find them.

I didn't move anything else to my application.rb, or production.rb, in case you're wondering. I think this may have a more elegant solution, but this works for now.

Answer (score 0):

you should set in production.rb:

```
config.assets.compile = true
```

and in command line use:

```
  rake assets:precompile
```

before launching it your server.

Comment: They're already set like that. And yes, I've already ran the rake assets:precompile.

Comment: why did you add them to "vendor"? add it to app instead.

Comment: Cause they're bound to change by the developer, not by me. It's not just one particular CSS, there're many. It's part of a framework.